# How to use placeholders for prepared statement without using PDO object?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have the following requirement. I have four fields Company Name, Experience, Salary From, Salary To. Now I want user to enter any field he wants and the SELECT query will be fired based on user's input so for example if user enters only Experience and Salary From entries then the result would be to display all records which matches the entered experience and whose starting salary range is greater than entered salary from. So for this my query will be dynamically generated at run time so I need to use placeholders like done in PDO eg..

```
if(!empty($company)) {
    $where = $where."AND company_name LIKE :company ";
}
if(!empty($company)) {
    $companyFormat = "'%".$company."%'";$stmt->bind_param(":company",$companyForm‌​at);
}
```

Can I do this using mysqli object instead of PDO?

Comment: forget it. with mysqli it will be so complex that you will never be able to support this code.

Comment: search mysqli prepared.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I bet you won't be able to accomplish this task even after an extensive search.

Comment: with mysqli would be somehow impossible, then he does not want PDO